# Angular shared property from an injected service not working

Tags: angularjs

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mSrK9q?p=preview)

I have this service I inject in my controllers. It is simply a service to share some properties.

```
angular.module('app', []).
service('sharedProperties', function () {
    var list_name = '';

    return {
        getListName: function() {
            return list_name;
        },
        setListName: function(name) {
            list_name = name;
        }
    };
});
```

I have two controllers. In the first one, I set the value of list_name. In my second, I want to retried this information.

Here is how are defined my controllers :

```
function ListCtrl($scope, $http, sharedProperties) {
   ...
   $scope.changeListName = function(list_name) {
 sharedProperties.setListName(list_name);
 console.log(list_name, sharedProperties.getListName());    # shows ( 'metro', 'metro')  == metro being a dummy list_name
   ...
};

function ItemCtrl($scope, $http, sharedProperties) {
    ...
    $scope.showOnlyList = sharedProperties.getListName();
    console.log(this.sharedProperties.getListName());           # empty string
    ...
};
```

I logged the variable and checked them in the browser console and noticed that ListCtrl sets the shared Property properly. The issue comes from the ItemCtrl controller. It seems that when I try to access the list_name with `sharedProperties.getListName();`, the property is empty, or the function returns an empty string.

**UPDATE**

I thought the problem came from the service. So I decided to use [Lungojs' data library](http://lungo.tapquo.com/howto/data/).

I got the following code :

In ListCtrl :

```
$scope.changeListName = function(list_name) {
        Lungo.Data.Cache.set("ListName", list_name);
        console.log('LIST', Lungo.Data.Cache.get("ListName"));
    };
```

In ItemCtrl :

```
$scope.showOnlyList = Lungo.Data.Cache.get("ListName");
console.log('ITEM', Lungo.Data.Cache.get("ListName"));
```

The log in ListCtrl shows that the cache is set to the correct list_name. However, the console for ItemCtrl shows that `Lungo.Data.Cache.get("ListName")` is undefined even if it was correct on the ListCtrl!

I also tried replacing the cache by HTML5 local storage without success...

Comment: why are u using this ?? in console.log

Comment: console.log is simply to get a trace of how my vars are defined. I can access the log inside Safari.

Comment: I mean to ask why u are using this.shareproperties in console.log anyways it would be better if you set up a plunker or fiddle demo of your code

Comment: I didn't think about that. But you are right it would be simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think its because you instantly log your sharedListPropery to the console, right after instantiating your ItemCtrl.
When it is instantiated, sharedPropertyList has no value yet.

EDIT:
Sry, JSFiddle is currently not working, so I have to put this untested code here.
But it should give you an idea

```
angular.module('app', []).
service('sharedProperties', function () {
  var list_name = '';

  return {
      getListName: function() {
          return list_name;
      },
      setListName: function(name) {
        list_name = name;
      }
  };
}).
controller('ListCtrl',['$scope','sharedProperties',function(scope,shared){
  console.log(shared.getListName()); //empty, because nothing set yet.
  scope.listname = shared.getListName();
  //watching the change and updating the shared
  scope.$watch('listname',function(value){
    console.log('listname is now '+value);
    shared.setListName(value); 
  })
  //watching the shared directly
  scope.shared=shared;
  scope.$watch('shared.getListName()',function(value){
      console.log("sharedProperty has changed to"+value);
  })

}]);
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your solution. What do you suggest?

Comment: wait for a fiddle please ;)

Comment: Is my problem supposed to be solve by using this code? Right now, the only thing I get in the console is `undefined`.

Comment: Hmm... Can you see what is wrong in my plunker? I will further investigate yours.

Comment: I studied your code and my problem is now solved! Thank you so much!

Comment: There is no need to declare $scope.shared =shared just directly put a watch on service function like  $scope.$watch(function()
  {
    return sharedProperties.getListName();
    }, function(value) {
    console.log('hello');
 // sharedProperties.setListName(value);
//  $scope.showOnlyList = sharedProperties.getListName();
 })